# Shopify - Get shop domain inside a app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, polaris

I'm new to Shopify app developing and I'm using Node,Express for the back-end and react with polaris libaray.

My question is how to get the shop's domain the request is initiating throug h the app. When I searched I could only found one used in Ruby `ShopifyAPI::Shop.current` and I'm looking for the similar thing to use in node?

Comment: Do I have to use cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For examples check out https://github.com/BKnights/kotn-shopify-utils
Yes it uses a session.
The code is pretty idiosyncratic. I published it mostly as an easy way to share between my own projects but it's worked pretty well for those.

If you use this where you may scale your servers you'd need to replace the session engine with something more distributed. Cookie sessions work.

This expects to route the setup page of the app to /preferences. Look at that route with the `validSession, session,` middleware

For passing the domain to Polaris I put the shop info into a plain JS object on the containing page (it's a dustjs template):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var KotN = {
        shop:'{shop}',
        apiKey: '{apiKey}',
        shopOrigin: 'https://{shop}.myshopify.com',
        locale:'{locale}' || (navigator.languages ? (navigator.language || navigator.languages[0]) : (navigator.userLanguage || navigator.browerLanguage))
    };
  </script>
```

and then the Polaris component looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {EmbeddedApp} from '@shopify/polaris/embedded';
import ShopProvider from './stores/ShopProvider';
import  Status from './views/status';


const shop = KotN.shop;
const shopOrigin = KotN.shopOrigin;
const apiKey = KotN.apiKey;

console.log('shop: '+ shop +' and origin: '+ shopOrigin);


export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <EmbeddedApp
        apiKey={apiKey}
        shopOrigin={shopOrigin}
        forceRedirect={true}
        debug={true}
      >
        <ShopProvider>
          <Status />
        </ShopProvider>
      </EmbeddedApp>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I think I understood this. I'll comment if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old thread but i've stumbled here while i was searching for the answer and just wanted to share my solution with you guys that also have the same problem. This is how i'm getting shop domain.

```
let shopDomain = new URL(window.location).searchParams.get("shop");
```

Answer (score 0):

After all of these years I think it will be easy to get the Shop domain from the below method

```
new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('shop')
```

This code snippet will get you the Shop domain of the currently installed shop.